# screen brightness gets maximum everytime on boot

Tags: grub2, screen, asus, brightness, 21.10

I'm using an AMD CPU

> the xbacklight didn't worked
> the backlight vendor also didn't worked

Comment: Saving brightness levels is broken on some new Ubuntu versions with some AMD GPUs. E.g it works with the 5.4 kernel on Ubuntu 20.04, but doesn't on 5.11. There are workarounds, but still not perfect. The problem is with systemd and kernel change.

Comment: @Pilot6 would be good to elaborate on that in a real answer, including current workarounds

Comment: There is completely no information in the question about the hardware. I chose to keep 5.4 for my Picasso, because workrounds with systemd had some annoying glitches.

Comment: Laptop is asus rog g513 (2021) , Cpu - 4800h , gpu - GTX 1650

Answer (score 0):

I always had the same issue and got to know that this occurs when
I install a kernel that has `unsigned` packages.
I have installed the 5.14.11(Signed) kernel now it works fine.